# ScrollView shows content in Android Studio but not in app

Tags: android, android-layout, switch-statement, scrollview

I'm trying to have a layout like this
[image: Layout in Android Studio]

however when I install it onto my S7 edge it looks like this:

[image: Galaxy S7 edge in portrait, ScrollView not displaying]

I'm not too sure what I am doing wrong, since it works when the device is in landscape.

[image: Galaxy S7 edge in landscape, works fine]

Here's my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HttpResponse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enable Features"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="456dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Switch"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Switch"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Switch"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/RequestKey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the "Layout and bounds" for the layout:

[image]

(The area on the right hand side is for the edge display, disregard it.)

Comment: Did you try removing the weightSum as you aren't using weights?

Comment: @NickCardoso Just tried it without, no change.

Comment: And what about when you give the switches a set height (not wrap)

Comment: @NickCardoso Set it to 40dp, gaps got larger still no switch though. [Here's the bounds](http://imgur.com/a/P7rly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the width of your `ScrollView` is too large for the portrait orientation, try setting it to `match_parent` :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">
```

**EDIT**

To apply side margins to your `ScrollView` use :

```
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. How would I remove say 20px from each side?